# how to set a default value in ckeditor 4?

Tags: ckeditor4.x

Refer to this question: https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Retrieving-default-value-database

I want to set a default value in ckeditor 4, like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="<!--I want to display this-->" required>
```

Anyone here can help?

Comment: By default CKEditor uses  <textarea>.  Try using textarea instead of input and you can pass the default content inside textarea field like this.   <textarea> YOUR DEFAULT CONTENT HERE</textarea>

Comment: I have changed it to <textarea> but still no success.

Comment: Check this documentation there is a sample code in bottom : 
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/classic.html